# laravel 5.4 variable parameter in query, giving wrong result?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
$ids = '1, 2, 3';
$data = Modelname::whereNotIn('id', [$ids])->take(1)->get();
```

Above query giving wrong result. but following query giving right result.

```
$data = Modelname::whereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->take(1)->get();
```

So, how to pass the variable parameter in **query(laravel 5.4)**.

Comment: `$ids` variable contains the above string or `array` of ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below to make array

```
$ids = '1, 2, 3';
$idArr = explode(", ",$ids);
$data = Modelname::whereNotIn('id', $idArr)->take(1)->get();
```

Take care of space among ids `$ids = '1, 2, 3';` and `exploding by string`

Answer (score 0):

The `whereNotIn` accepts an `array` as its second argument.

So if you have a comma separated string which you do in your first scenario you need to explode it into an array, and then pass it to `whereNotIn`.

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
$idsArray = explode(',', $ids); // produces [1, 2, 3]
// it's always a good idea to add a check because if array is empty then an SQL exception will be thrown.
if(count($idsArray) > 0) {
   $data = Modelname::whereNotIn('id', $idsArray)->take(1)->get();
}
```

Hope this helps.